# How to make multiple Spring HandlerInterceptors execute in a specific order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I'm currently working on a Spring boot project. I have a dependency on a library project that has an interceptor(**LibraryProjectInterceptor.java**) and a `public class LibraryProjectConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer` and overrides the `addInterceptors()` method to add the `LibraryProjectInterceptor` to the `InterceptorRegistry`. In my actual project where I added this library project dependency, I have created an interceptor(`ActualProjectInterceptor`) that needs to be executed after the `LibraryProjectInterceptor` has been executed. I have tried adding `@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` to the `ActualProjectInterceptor` to make it execute after the `LibraryProjectInterceptor` but it is not working. Can someone help me

Library Project:

```
public class LibraryProjectInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
 ......
}




  @Configuration
  @EnableWebMVC
  public class LibraryProjectConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ......
        @Override
            public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
                registry.addInterceptor(LibraryProjectInterceptor);
            }
    ......
    }
```

Actual Project:
***pom.xml***

```
 ......

<dependencies>
 <dependency> 
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>library-project</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.16</version>
 </dependency>
 ......

@Component
@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ActualProjectInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
.......
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class ActualProjectConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
......
    @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(ActualProjectInterceptor);
        }
......
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I hope it will be working.

```java
@Component
public class ActualProjectInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {}

@SpringBootApplication
public class ActualProjectConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(ActualProjectInterceptor)
                .order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

`addInterceptor()` method creates the [InterceptorRegistration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.html) DSL object which has `order()` method to specify what you need.

Comment: Hey. Thanks man! It worked. I wonder why the @Order annotation didnt work. Can you please explain that

Comment: I cant answer without seeing the actual codebase
`registry.addInterceptor(ActualProjectInterceptor)` -> `ActualProjectInterceptor` this name was the reference to Spring Bean or you used the `new` operator to create the object. If the second option, I think that `@Order` will not work because is strongly associated with the Spring engine, creating a class as an ordinal bean (without Spring support) can be the root cause.

Comment: Yeah! I think you are correct. The 'LibraryProjectInterceptor' was added to the registry using 'new' operator like this registry.addInterceptor(new LibraryProjectInterceptor());